# Input form to change relative URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, input

I have got a problem. 
I need to have an simple input form which will change the relative URL of the page. Lets say i've got *site.com/index*

```
<form>
<p>
  <label for="url"</label>
  <input id="url" type="text" onchange="var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', this.value); this.value = a.href; window.location.search="/a.href";" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</p> </form>
```

Where did i go wrong? Whatever i type in the form, it will redirect me to *site.com/index?* 
Maybe i got it wrong and this can only be handled on the backend. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the folloiwng

```
<form>
<p>
  <label for="url"</label>
  <input id="url" type="text" onchange="window.location='/'+this.value;" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</p> </form>
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work - still redirects page to `index?`.